# VSCode dart analyzer stopped recognizing flutter/dart code

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

I have been using VSCode for flutter development without issue, then today all of a sudden the dart analyzer is complaining that the majority of the classes are undefined, or targets do not exists.

Has anyone seen this before?

I have restarted VSCode, restarted computer, uninstalled flutter/dart plugins, ran flutter doctor with no issues...I am out of ideas.

[VSCode Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpzMW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the VS Code "Laravel blade spacer" extension. Once I removed the add on, I no longer had the problem

Comment: i dont have this extention

Answer (score 10):

Go to ***pubspec.yaml***, right click and do *Get Packages*.
It seems to work for me all the time.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I ran that command manually which didn't fix it, but right clicking and get packages worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

The issue might be caused by VSCode struggling to find the Dart SDK installation path, even if it's in your Windows PATH.

To fix, just give the Dart extension an explicit reference to your SDK installation(s) using the extension settings ([Ctrl + ,], type 'Dart:') or by directly editing `settings.json` ([Ctrl + Shift + P], type 'settings.json', [Enter]).

If you have both Flutter and the full Dart SDK installed, add both listings:

```
"dart.sdkPaths": [
  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dart\\dart-sdk\\bin",
  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk\\bin",
],
```

If you have only one installed (most commonly just Flutter), you can just add that one:

```
"dart.sdkPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk\\bin",
```

Bonus bit: The multiple-SDK settings are great (and in fact intended) when developing different projects requiring various SDK versions. I find this is especially useful when working on multiple projects over several months or even years, especially considering how rapidly and regularly both Dart and Flutter are changing and maturing at present.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be.. to delete the dart SDK (the cache folder under the bin dir of  flutter SDK). And use the cmd as admin to re download the sdk, by running flutter doctor.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too then I reinstalled dart and flutter plugin from androod studio and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, de-installing then re-installing VS Code did the trick !

I came to that conclusion after talking to someone on the Dart/Flutter Extension server on Discord.

[image: Got help on Discord]

Answer (score 0):

My Dart sdk path is misplaced....so change it on vs code ...
GO to settings search dart and then click on dart anaylzer path
next step is  change this path to flutter SDK folder if it is wrong.

"dart.flutterSdkPath": "D:\CLG\flutter",

Answer (score 0):

try uninstalling your flutter and dart extension on vs code and then reinstalled them