# Dart Analyzer terminated on flutter clean or flutter run

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-analyzer

Whenever I use the command `flutter clean` or `flutter run`, the window "The Dart Analyzer has terminated." pops up in VS Code.
For `flutter run` I can specify that the analyzer terminates when it says "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'" in the console.

Here is the log after running `flutter clean`: https://hastebin.com/osovilenaj.swift

Can someone tell me the reason for this behaviour? I can simply click on restart, but it is annoying during my workflow.

Comment: some time it happens when vscode needs a restart. Try manually restarting vscode. Also first check for update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since something (Dart?) has been updated the error does not occurre anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update and restart both PC and VSCode, see if the problem persist.

It generally used to happen to me when either my `CPU` is doing too much work or the `RAM` is exhausted, see if you have same problem either with `CPU` or `RAM` use a `real device` to test with `USB Debugging enabled` instead of `Emulator`.

also this might also help [VSCode dart analyzer stopped recognizing flutter/dart code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488236/vscode-dart-analyzer-stopped-recognizing-flutter-dart-code)

Comment: I have this problem since a few weeks, so I have already restarted my PC and VS Code many times. My CPU and RAM usage when I run flutter run: https://ibb.co/CJrNwck I am using my phone instead of an Emulator already. I am on the latest VS Code version.

Comment: so the Dart analyser must be stopping when your CPU Usage reaches 100% or near 100% I guess??

Comment: I just ran it again and now I am far away from 100% usage: https://ibb.co/JKs0K1V , but the analyzer still terminates.

Comment: Its a little bit strange as I can see you have 16gigs of RAM you must not encounter this problem

Comment: @PlutoHDDev check the link that I have recently added it might help..

Comment: That's right, it's not video editing, it's just programming and running apps on my phone... A friend of mine is working on the same app (->GitHub) and he doesn't have this problem.

Comment: You can also try reinstalling dart, there might some error in the PATH ..

Comment: I already reinstalled Flutter and Dart in the VS Code Extensions. Do I also have to reinstall dart somewhere else? Which link do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488236/vscode-dart-analyzer-stopped-recognizing-flutter-dart-code this one

Comment: not talking about extensions, talking about dart SDK try to reinstall it

Comment: I now installed the dart-sdk (before I just had the flutter dart-sdk), moved it above the flutter dart-sdk in my PATH variable and also configured the paths in the dart extension. I also deleted the flutter cache folder and let flutter install all that again using flutter doctor. After a restart... no change. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Nothing more coming to my mind for now, until than you can also raise an issue on flutter Github there some more people can look into it.